# understand a sequence of redirections

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

If several redirections are used together, does changing their order make difference?

How shall one understand the meaning of their order? Is the chained channel of redirections built as reading the redirections from left to right, or from right to left?

For example

```
command 2>&1 > somefile

command > somefile 2>&1
```

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the order makes a difference, and they should be read left to right.

`command 2>&1 >somefile` means to redirect stderr (2) to the current destination of stdout (the terminal).  Then change stdout to go to `somefile`.  So stderr goes to the terminal, and stdout goes to a file.

`command >somefile 2>&1` means to redirect stdout to `somefile`, and then to redirect stderr to the same destination as stdout (the file).  So both stderr and stdout go to `somefile`.

This is explained in [section 3.6 of the Bash manual: Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
man bash
```

says:

> REDIRECTION
>          Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected
>   using a special notation interpreted
>   by the shell.   Redi‐
>          rection may also be used to open and close files for the current
>   shell execution environment.  The
>   following redirection opera‐
>          tors may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or
>   may follow a command.  Redirections
>   are processed in  the  order
>          they appear, from left to right.

and

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the command
>
> `ls > dirlist 2>&1`
>
> directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> `ls 2>&1 > dirlist`
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was duplicated from the standard output before the
>          standard output was redirected to dirlist.