# Redirect standard error during concatenate using cat

Tags: find, cat, stderr

Need some help on redirecting error to stdout for the below command

```
find /mypath/env/test/ -name "*.tmp" -exec cat '{}' ';' >> /mypath/env/final/merged.txt 2>&1
```

This command works great when the paths are correct.  In case if the paths are not correct, then it is throwing error 'No such file or directory'.

How do I redirect this error to 'stdout'.  I already added '2>&1' at the end, but it doesn't seem to work.  Need your expert advice on this.  Thanks.

Comment: I think `2>&1`  redirects stderr to stdout.  It sounds like you want to filter out stderr.  In that case, redirect it to `/dev/null` with `2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Stewart you correct.  My bad, I want the error to be redirected to stdout

Comment: With your current command, you are redirecting stderr to stdout.  Look inside merged.txt.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes, the errors are inside the 'merged.txt'.  But I need those errors to be captured in stdout instead that going inside the file.

Comment: Then you just remove '2>&1'.

Comment: You haven't mentioned *why* you want to redirect stderr to stdout. If you want to redirect standard output to a file, but redirect standard error to standard output for further processing in a pipeline, then you just need to switch the order of redirections. See for example [understand a sequence of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/understand-a-sequence-of-redirections)

Comment: I'm very confused by the the question. There are two different stdouts involved: in the script's general context, stdout is probably something like a terminal; for the `find` command (and the `cat` command(s) it runs), stdout is /mypath/env/final/merged.txt. Which one are you trying to redirect stderr to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the errors in a file, then:

```
find /mypath/env/test/ -name "*.tmp" -exec cat '{}' ';' >> /mypath/env/final/merged.txt 2>/mypath/env/final/merged.err
```