# How can I redirect stdout and stderr to multiple files in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to redirect the stdout and stderr of `command` to `logfile.txt` *and* to `otherfile.txt`.

At the moment, I'm capturing both like this:

```
command  >> logfile.txt 2>> logfile.txt
```

That works, but what doesn't work is this:

```
node myscript.js 2>&1 >> logfile.txt
```

This only records stdout.  It's a problem that it doesn't work, because if I want to add a second file, the methods I've found to do that involve the `2>&1` method with `tee`.

I'm on Linux Mint 19, with Bash version 4.4.20(1)-release.

Comment: I have no idea why just asking this on stackexchange made it worked, when I'd specifically tried this before posting, but it does now, so thank-you.

With one update, I added -a to `tee` in order for it to not overwrite logfile.txt

Comment: When ever you find yourself writing things like "the methods I've found to do that involve ...", you really need to show what those methods you tried were. Right now, it's really easy to read this question as just being about the order of `>>` and `2>&1`.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [understand a sequence of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16360/86440), the order of redirections is significant:

```
node myscript.js 2>&1 >> logfile.txt
```

redirects standard error to whatever standard output is pointing at, and then redirects standard output to `logfile.txt`, *without* touching standard error.

You need to switch the order:

```
node myscript.js >> logfile.txt 2>&1
```

will record both outputs in `logfile.txt`.

However this isn’t relevant if you want to pipe to `tee`:

```
node myscript.js 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.txt otherfile.txt
```