# Redirecting STDOUT to STDERR 1>&2 with sh

Tags: shell

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between the order of 1>&2 and >. For example, I have `file` and `file` and don't have fie. Then `diff fie file2` gives me error and I try redirecting the error message to stdout as follows:

```
$ diff fie file2 > out.log 2>&1
$ cat out.log
diff: fie: No such file or directory
```

However, if I reverse the order as

```
$ diff fie file2 2>&1 > out2.log
diff: fie: No such file or directory
$ cat out2.log
$
```

the output is different. Why is this? and if the STDERR and STDERR are merged by 2>&1, will the file descriptor 2 be empty? and can anyone point to a reference about >& and <& ? Thank you.

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/why-is-redirecting-stderr-to-dev-null-done-this-way , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84279/is-this-a-typo-in-bash-manuals-redirection-section , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16360/understand-a-sequence-of-redirections and the example into the reference manual about order of redirection: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: `2>&1` basically means "take whatever it is that fd 1 points to right now, and make fd 2 also point to the same place"

Comment: Thank you so much!